# How can I pass value from one component from another component in Angular8 (Independent components)

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I want to reset the value of a variable of another component. 2 components are independent ones. I want to reset the value of the particular variable. Once the value is updated need to refresh the UI of that component to reflect the changes.

Expecting something like **Broadcast/Emit and On** in AngularJS

Is it possible to do something with RxJS? If yes please share me some useful links.

Comment: Something to read: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: There is a [very good guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) demonstrating the multiple ways independent components can interact/share data on the angular.io docs [https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a Service to share an EventEmitter: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

```
@Injectable()
export class YourSharedService {
  private _event = new EventEmitter<any>();

  get event(): EventEmitter<any> {
    return this._event;
  }
}
```

Then just emit in the first component:

```
this.yourService.event.emit();
```

And subscribe in the other:

```
    this.yourService.event.subscribe(() =>  {});
```

Usefull, only if your components are really independent.